# YAML Validation in java failing

Tags: java, yaml, jackson-dataformat-yaml

I am getting following error when trying to validate json data using YAML schema. I am using networknt library as given [here](https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator/blob/master/doc/yaml.md)

> com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.error.MarkedYAMLException:
> mapping values are not allowed here  in 'reader', line 1, column 58:
>
> ```
>  ... -schema.org/draft-04/schema#type: objectproperties:  id:    type ... 
>                                      ^
> ```
>
> at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 58]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.error.MarkedYAMLException.from(MarkedYAMLException.java:27)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLParser.nextToken(YAMLParser.java:359)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.nextFieldName(JsonParser.java:861)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:250)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:68)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:15)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readTreeAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4270)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2720)
> at
> com.nike.nifi.validatejson.App.getJsonNodeFromStringContent(App.java:53)
> at com.nike.nifi.validatejson.App.validate(App.java:36)     at
> com.nike.nifi.validatejson.App.main(App.java:25)

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory;
import com.networknt.schema.JsonSchema;
import com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaFactory;
import com.networknt.schema.SpecVersion;
import com.networknt.schema.ValidationMessage;
        
    public boolean validate() {
        boolean isValid = false;
        try {
            String inputJsonString = getFileData("C:\\Projects\\data\\input.json");
            JsonNode node = getJsonNodeFromStringContent(inputJsonString);

            String schema = getFileData("C:\\Projects\\data\\yamlfrmjsonschema.yml");
            JsonNode schemaNode = getJsonNodeFromStringContent(schema);
            JsonSchema validator = getJsonSchemaFromJsonNodeAutomaticVersion(schemaNode);

            Set<ValidationMessage> errors = validator.validate(node);
            
            if (errors.isEmpty()) {
                isValid = !isValid;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return isValid;
    }
    
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());

    private JsonNode getJsonNodeFromStringContent(String content) throws IOException {
        return mapper.readTree(content);
    }

    private JsonSchema getJsonSchemaFromJsonNodeAutomaticVersion(JsonNode jsonNode) {       
        JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.builder(JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(SpecVersion.VersionFlag.V7)).objectMapper(mapper).build(); 
        return factory.getSchema(jsonNode);
    }
```

Input.json

```
    {
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "image":
        {
            "url": "images/0001.jpg",
            "width": 200,
            "height": 200
        },
    "thumbnail":
        {
            "url": "images/thumbnails/0001.jpg",
            "width": 32,
            "height": 32
        }
}
```

YAML

```
---
"$schema": http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#
type: object
properties:
  id:
    type: string
  type:
    type: string
  name:
    type: string
  image:
    type: object
    properties:
      url:
        type: string
      width:
        type: integer
      height:
        type: integer
    required:
    - url
    - width
    - height
  thumbnail:
    type: object
    properties:
      url:
        type: string
      width:
        type: integer
      height:
        type: integer
    required:
    - url
    - width
    - height
required:
- id
- type
- name
- image
- thumbnail
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with you schema yaml.

At least it is my wild guess. It seems that your schema declaration is wrong.
[Asdf standard](https://asdf-standard.readthedocs.io/en/1.5.0/schemas/yaml_schema.html#Original%20Schema) has an example in which the schema value is quoted, not the property itself.
So try to change the first line of your schema to this:

```yaml
---
$schema: "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"
```

Edit: And you may have to remove or change the first `type: object` -> `- type: object`

Comment: Still there is error  com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.error.MarkedYAMLException: while parsing a block mapping
 in 'reader', line 1, column 1:
    ---$schema: "http://json-schema. ... 
    ^
expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'
 in 'reader', line 1, column 54:
     ... son-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"type: objectproperties:  id:     ...

Comment: when changing yaml schema  - type: object com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.error.MarkedYAMLException: sequence entries are not allowed here
 in 'reader', line 1, column 54:
     ... son-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"- type: objectproperties:  id:   ...

Comment: Then you may need to remove the `$schema` line entirely. As it seems to be an issue with this line.

Or you have encountered a bug in the networknt implementation. They use the schema definition in the json schema examples, but are missing an explicit example for the yaml schema usecase. You may open an issue there and ask to improve the documentation and clarify

Comment: I tried removing schema from yaml to get following error   com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.error.MarkedYAMLException: mapping values are not allowed here
 in 'reader', line 1, column 26:
    ---type: objectproperties:  id:    type: string  type:    ...   where the error is now at objectproperties:  id